# 2d array representation through pointer

Tags: c

Addresses of 1d arrays are actually taken as

```
a[i]=*(a+i);
```

Are the addresses of 2d arrays calculated as

```
a[i][j]=**(a+i+j);
```

Comment: no, at least because a[0][1] and a[1][0] would point to the same memory in that case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are not quite correct.  It's more like:

```
*(*(a+i)+j)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply the rule recursively:

```
a[i][j] == *(a[i] + j) == *(*(a + i) + j)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because then `a[1][2]` and `a[2][1]` would be at the same place. Something like `*(a+i*n+j)` for an n-by-m array is closer to the mark (though beware I type the exact expression into a markdown editor, not a unit test).

Answer (score 0):

```
// CTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

void print (int i, int j )
{
    int a[3][3] = {
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4,5,6 },
        { 7,8,9 }
        };
    printf ("%d\n", *(*(a+i)+j) );
    printf ("%d\n", a[i][j] );
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    print (0,0);
    print (1,1);
    print (2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Returns:

1
1
5
5
9
9

*This has been run through a compiler....

Comment: @codymanix: There is no double dereferencing, so the type of all that is pointer-to-int.

Answer (score 0):

No. `a` and `a[i]` are of different types (respectively `int**` and `int*`).

Supposing that in your example `a` was defined as array of array of int (eg `a[10][20]`), when you pass it to a function (thereby converting it to `pointer to the first element of the array`) you have (with further "simplifications" for the 2nd array rank)

```
    a           is of type `int**`
    a[i]        is of type `int*`
    a[i][j]     is of type `int`

    *(a+i)      is of type `int*`
    a+i+j       is of type `int**`
    *(a+i+j)    is of type `int*`
    *(*(a+i)+j) is of type `int`
```

Comment: If `a` is indeed a "2d array" (by which we normally mean an array of arrays) then it decays to type `int (*)[n]`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "further simplification for the 2nd rank". Thank you for making it clearer.

Comment: It's not right though - if `a` is defined as `a[10][20]` then `a` is **not** of type `int**`, it's of type `int(*)[20]`.